# Google Cloud TypeError: Cannot read property 'Reader' of undefined

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-translate

My Google Cloud Function won't upload if I include this line, which came from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/quickstart#translate_translate_text-nodejs):

```js
const {Translate} = require('@google-cloud/translate').v2;
```

The error is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Reader' of undefined
```

There's no `Reader` in my code.

My version is:

```
npm -v @google-cloud/translate
6.14.10
```

Which is odd, because the [current npm version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/translate) is 6.0.5, and the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/release-notes) say there hasn't been an update since March 2020.

I tried both Node 10 and Node 12 for the Firebase Cloud Functions engine, same error.

Am I getting this error because I'm on the event horizon of a black hole and downloaded a future version of `@google-cloud/translate`? I think I might be in an alternative universe, 2020 was awful. How are things in your universe?

Comment: upvote just because you come from an alternative universe

Answer (score 4):

I updated the npm modules in my `/functions` directory and the error message is gone. Both `firebase-functions` and `@google-cloud/translate` were out of date.